# ReactJS: How do replace a string with new elements in a 'react-way'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how I'm trying to replace some strings with elements inside the `render()`-method of my component. But this fails, as I'm getting the replaced string as a real string instead of an elements.

What do I have to do, to get `Link` as a **rendered** `Link`-element? Right now it is just a string output.

And is this the correct 'react'-way to do that?

```
return (
  <List>
    {
      elements.map(e => {
        return (
          <List.Item>
            {
              links ? links.map(link => {
                return e.content.replace(
                  new RegExp(link.label, 'gi'),
                    '<Link to="/' + link.id + '">$&</Link> (<Icon name="external" />)'
                )
              }) : ''
            }
          </List.Item>
        )
      })
    }
  </List>
)
```

**elements**

```
[{
    "_id" : "zQS6pXicvXk7K2rZ4",
    "content" : "This is a sample text to add some links",
    "links" : [
        {
            "id" : "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
            "type" : "articles",
            "label" : "Sample"
        },
        {
            "id" : "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P",
            "type" : "articles",
            "label" : "add"
        },
        {
            "id" : "XpaiZDn5GhkJ9y87P",
            "type" : "articles",
            "label" : "External"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: What does `elements` typically look like? And `links`?

Comment: Both are object arrays.

Comment: I get that from your code, but it would help seeing example data.

Comment: I see. You need to split `content` into an array of strings, like `["This is a", "sample", "text to", "add", "some links"]` according to the `label`s, then replace the array elements with `<Link />`s.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First replace the `string` by the `Link` then `render` the `string` by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`,  it should work.

Check this example:

```js
let data = [{
    "_id" : "zQS6pXicvXk7K2rZ4",
    "content" : "This is a sample text to add some links",
    "links" : [
        {
            "id" : "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
            "type" : "articles",
            "label" : "sample"
        },
        {
            "id" : "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P",
            "type" : "articles",
            "label" : "add"
        },
        {
            "id" : "XpaiZDn5GhkJ9y87P",
            "type" : "articles",
            "label" : "External"
        }
    ]
}];


var App = () => {
return (
  <div>
    {
      data.map(e => {
        return (
          <div>
            {
              e.links ? e.links.map(link => {
                return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: e.content.replace(new RegExp(link.label, 'g'),
                    '<a href="/' + link.id + '">$&</a> (<Icon name="external" />)'
                )}} ></div>
              }) : ''
            }
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
)
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: But now you're using `<a>`, not `<Link>`.

Comment: @ChrisG this was an example how to write, `Link` will not work here so i used `a` tag, and it is working properly. Same code will work for `Link` also because `Link` finally get rendered as `a` tag only (just a wrapper of `a` tag) :)

Comment: The thing is though, `Link` will *not* get rendered as `<a>`. That's the entire issue in the first place: how to replace part of a string with a React element, as opposed to just text. Only if the string is split into an array, and `<Link />`s are inserted as elements will it work as expected. Your answer does not address the actual problem.